# Match multiple lines in a file using python

Tags: python-2.7

In the below file I need to check if the last 3 lines are present (full line). If present the script exits else it adds those lines to the file

dev_server #cat p_file/common-password

password        requisite       pam_pwcheck.so nullok cracklib

password        required        pam_unix2.so use_authtok nullok

password        required        pam_cracklib.so dcredit=-1 ucredit=1 1credit=-1 minlen=8 retry=5

password        required        pam_pwhistory.so use_authok remember=3 retry=5

password        required        pam_pwcheck.so remember=5

password        required        pam_unix2.so use_authok

I am able to search only one line but want to search for all 3 lines in the file. Could anyone please suggest the best way to do that using python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for -2 rating, it helped me study/search for more and I got the answer, any help to better it will be appreciated. Thank you

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys,os,re

print ('Searcing for a line in /etc/pam.d/common-password\n')

pass_file = open('/root/p_file/common-password', 'r').readlines()

for i in pass_file:

    if re.search(r"password        required        pam_unix2.so use_authok\n", i):

        sys.exit("Sending exit code 0")

    else:

        sys.exit(2)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```